# Mobile website background images not displaying correctly on Blackberry Bold 9700

Tags: css, mobile, blackberry, web, sprite

I've built a mobile site using a CSS sprite for some of the icons etc but the images look really pixelated and jagged in the Blackberry Bold 9700's browser. Fine on a couple of other BB devices and everything else we've tested.

The sprite images also appear to be smaller so not sure if it's a scaling issue with the browser. The inline images look fine but also smaller than on other devices.

**Device details:**

*Bold 9700 - 6.0 Bundle 2049*

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching around I found the cause, image compression. I always run images through the ImageOptim app and it looks like this caused the extremely low resolution just on this handset. Exported the CSS sprite without compression and now it looks fine.

**EDIT:**

I thought compression was the problem but it's actually the dimensions of the image sprite! It was one long image, about 1400px high, and the Blackberry seems to automatically reduce the quality of large images, leading to all the problems.

**Fixed** it by simply separating the sprite in to 2 files about 600px high.